# Bundle install really slow on Jenkins Pipeline (AWS EC2 Instance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, amazon-ec2, bundle

I am running Jenkins on AWS EC2 Linux Instance and I am trying to bundle install the gems needed for my rails repo on GitHub.

It is a new project that I created for testing but the bundle takes hours, Jenkins freezes and I need to restart the server and Jenkins and it never finishes installing the gems in the end.

This is my code:

```
    pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'ruby:2.6.6' } }
    stages {
        stage('Fetching Git') {

            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'user-key',
                    url: 'git@github.com:user/jenkins_project.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {

            steps {
                sh 'gem install bundler'
                sh 'bundle install --jobs 4'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {

            steps {
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out result_spec.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried doing is:

1. Using --jobs when bundle install (it doesn't seem to work)
2. Using http instead of https on the Gemfile when on

   source 'http://rubygems.org'

I know it is unsafe. And this doesn't seem to work either.
3.
Also tried this:

```
echo 'export MAKE="make -j$(nproc)"' >> $home/.bash_profile
time MAKE="make --jobs 8" bundle install
```

From here (https://build.betterup.com/one-weird-trick-that-will-speed-up-your-bundle-install/). But it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on why is this happening and how can I solve it greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any logs of the jenkins job leading to more specific context for example bundle couldn't connected and is retrying to install or something similar for the build job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by:

1. Creating a master server with Java & Jenkins
2. Creating a slave server (called 'linux_slave') with Java & Git & Docker

The code would be something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ruby:2.6.6'
            label 'linux_slave'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Fetching Git') {
            
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'user-key',
                    url: 'git@github.com:user/jenkins_project.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'gem install bundler:2.0.1'
                sh 'bundle install'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone in need sometime!

Answer (score 0):

add this as first line before gem install as each installed package will be less in size because no documenation is been downloaded with it

```
sh 'echo gem: --no-document > ~/.gemrc'
```

I have used this for Travis and it helped a lot
I am not fully sure for Jenkins syntax but try the following one

```
        stage('Build') {

        steps {
            sh 'echo gem: --no-document > ~/.gemrc' 
            sh 'gem install bundler'
            sh 'bundle install --jobs 4'
            sh 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and gives an error. Change it a little bit 
```sh 'echo gem: --no-document > ~/.gemrc' ```
and it works! Would have to try running the whole thing on master to know if it works 100% or not. Even then, I think it is best to divide the workload between slaves